# Outside Tokyo: Where for flora, landscape, nature?

Tags: japan, nature-and-wildlife, rural

As I'm ruling out Tokyo in this post, this doesn't duplicate [Within 300 km of Tokyo: Where for flora, landscape, nature?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31143/13759).  Please recommend where to enjoy picturesque backwoods? Criteria:

1. No dangerous animals or untamed boondocks. No [Caniformia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caniformia) or snakes.
2. I won't drive, and must rely on public transport and walking less than 5 km in total.
3. No shrines, temples or any religious edifice.
4. OPTIONAL: I fancy  [water bodies](https://en.wikipedia.orgwiki/Body_of_water), the more  the better.

Comment: @AdityaSomani But ostensibly not in Hokkaido: see the last paragraph at http://www.frommers.com/destinations/hokkaido/620545#sthash.GGHZJ6fy.dpbs

Comment: Ah yes yes. Hokkaido. Of course. I meant "most" of Japan. Even in Hokkaido though, there is a decent amount of public transport. Here's a [map](http://www2.jrhokkaido.co.jp/global/english/rmap/route_map.pdf) only from JR Hokkaido, other companies run trains too.

Comment: Re 2, some parts of "northern Honshu" are farther away from the Fukushima power plant than Tokyo is. -1.

Comment: Japan is as full of picturesque rural areas as it is full of metropolises. I believe it is the greenest developed country in the world. There's not much virgin untouched land though. Also you can get almost anywhere easily on the train system other than in Okinawa and Hokkaido. Of course the most backwoods areas are the least near the train system like in Okinawa, Hokkaido, and perhaps some of the harder to reach islands. Bears are rare but exist in mountains in the north, the only other dangerous wildlife would be the habu snakes in Okinawa and the giant hornets.

Comment: We don't give advice on where to visit.